# double free detected in tcache 2 when calling erase() on std::set

Tags: c++, stdset, double-free

i was writing a simple code for testing purposes. if i declare the `node1` first, there's no problem but when i declare the `node2` first, the code give me `free(): double free detected in tcache2`.

- could someone please explain the reason for this `double free` error?

  ```
  class node1;
  class node2;

  class node1{
   public:
       node1(void) = default;

       // member data
       int *n;
       std::set<node2*> tonode2;
  };

  class node2{
   public:
       node2(void) = default;

       ~node2(void){
           for(auto val:tonode1)
               val->tonode2.erase(this);           // free(): double free detected here..
       }

       // member data
       int *n;
       std::set<node1*> tonode1;
  };

  int main(void){
     node2 n2;
     node1 n1;

     n1.tonode2.insert(&n2);
     n2.tonode1.insert(&n1);

     return 0;
   }
  ```

the code compiled with g++ (GCC) 11.2.0 run on ubuntu 20.04.

Comment: `n1` is destroyed before `n2`, which still holds a reference.

Comment: Actually double deletion is just the visible effect of invoking undefined behaviour, which occurred earlier.

Comment: You might fix by letting `node1` remove it's references from `node2` as well, then `n2` gets destructed its set is cleared already. However, you rely on *always* mutually including nodes in their sets, so you should make the sets private and provide a function that does such mutual inclusion as the *only* way to do so.

Answer (score 3):

`n1` is destroyed first. When `n2` is destroyed, its destructor will indirect through the pointer that used to point to `n1`, but is now invalid. The behaviour of the program is undefined.

Answer (score 1):

You better use smart pointers such as `std::shared_ptr` instead of raw pointers when ownership is important. `std::weak_ptr` should be preferred if there are reference cycles as in your question.

And you should create them with `std::make_shared` in the main, so that objects will be owned by smart pointer. Because smart pointers assume they are the only owner of the enclosed object. Otherwise it will be destructed two times, once by the owner scope and once by the smart pointer, leading to a double free corruption.